# ASP.Net_SessionId cookie across subdomains using IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies, asp.net-session

I have two ASP.NET websites: new.somecompany.com and legacy.somecompany.com.

"New" is an intranet application that uses Windows Authentication.
"Legacy" is both internet and intranet; it uses Forms Authentication.

From within the "New" website, my boss would like to be able to click on a link and open up a browser window to an already logged in webpage on the "Legacy" site. (He wants this done without changes to the legacy site.)

I have a solution that work with both Chrome (version 39.0.2171.95 m) and Firefox (version 33.1.1), but not with Internet Explorer (version 11.0.9600.17501). At a high-level, the solution is:

1. A controller on "new" uses a HttpWebRequest to login to "legacy" using stored credentials.
2. The controller gets the "ASP.Net_SessionId" cookie from the "legacy" response and uses it to
   set "ASP.Net_SessionId" cookie for domain ".somecompany.com" in the browser.
3. From the browser, go to `https://legacy.somecompany.com/somepage.aspx`.

With Chrome and Firefox, the `https://legacy.somecompany.com/somepage.aspx` is displayed as appropriate for the stored credentials that were used to login.  With IE 11, the login page is displayed.

I used  Microsoft's Message Analyzer tool to see what is being passed back and forth. With Chrome, I see the ASP.Net_SessionId cookie being sent in the HTTP request for somepage.aspx. With IE 11, the cookie is not being sent and I get a redirect to the login page as a response.

Is there anything that I can do to get this to work in IE 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/11/troubleshooting-stored-login-problems-in-ie.aspx) gave me the answer.  In particular, this paragraph:

> Problem #3 occurs on Windows Vista and above, when you have configured
>   one subdomain to run outside of Protected Mode (e.g. put it in the
>   Trusted Zone) and another related subdomain to run inside of Protected
>   Mode (e.g. left it in the Internet Zone). This isn’t terribly common,
>   but might occur if you, for instance, put login.live.com in the
>   Trusted Zone but didn’t put mail.live.com in the Trusted Zone. The
>   root cause of this obscure problem is that Protected Mode and
>   non-Protected Mode do not share cookies, and hence a cookie set by a
>   site outside of Protected Mode will not be visible to a site running
>   inside Protected Mode, and vice versa.

In my case, "new.somecompany.com" was in the local intranet zone in IE's settings, but "legacy.somecompany.com" was not.  After adding "legacy.somecompany.com" to the intranet zone, my code worked in IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. Most recently I developed a web application that I wanted to code-once and deploy (in an iFrame) in a Windows Authenticate and Anonymous site.

The user must be logged in either by Active Director or Log into the external site.

This is how I handled it. In both cases the iFrame Site runs on the same domain (as you show) site1.company.com or site2.company.com

This is how I handled it.

1. Site A: User logs in, encrypt the user name and store it in a cookie. (I used AES encryption with a private key).
2. Site B: Read the cookie, decrypt the user id, and log the user into the site.

There is also an encrypted value (date time) in the cookie and it that value is checked for 3 seconds expiration.

Comment: Interesting answer, but it appears to require changes to the legacy site which is outside the current boundaries I have been given. I will keep this in mind if the other solution is technically impossible.